# Updating a many-to-many connector table all at once

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, relational-database

Say I have two tables:

```
articles
categories
```

There's a many to many table that connects them.

```
CREATE TABLE cat2art (
  article_id INT,
  category_id INT
);
```

For a specific article, I have a 'new list' of category id's, and we need to update the cat2art table with these.

Some categories got removed, some got added and some stayed where they were. What is the most effective way to update this table?

I could naively delete all records with the specified article_id and simply add them again. However, if I were to record a date in that same table that tracks when an article was linked to a category, that information will now be destroyed.

I'm looking for a great pattern that easily solves this issue. This question is specifically for PHP and MySQL, but answers in other languages are also fine provided they are applicable to PHP+MySQL as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other systems support `MERGE` statement which would do exactly what you want.

However, in `MySQL`, you would need at least two queries (it cannot delete and insert/update in a single statement):

```
DELETE
FROM    cat2art
WHERE   art_id = $art_id
        AND cat_id NOT IN ($new_cat_1, $new_cat_2, …);

INSERT
IGNORE
INTO    cat2art
VALUES
($art_id, $new_cat_1),
($art_id, $new_cat_2),
…;
```

Comment: Accepted this answer for being the closest to the answer I was looking for =)

Answer (score 2):

You can define (article_id, category_id) as unique key, and when inserting a connection use `INSERT IGNORE` syntax. That way if this connection already exists it will not be added again, nor will it update the existing record, and the create_date column stays untouched.

example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO cat2art (article_id, category_id, create_date) 
VALUES(100,200,NOW());
```

Comment: How would I know afterwards which records to delete?

Comment: @Evert - you'll need to run a delete query, similar to what Quassoni has suggested. I addressed the insertion issue assuming that's the more challenging part.

Comment: Neither is very challenging, but I was hoping for a nice re-usable pattern that inserts/updates/deletes these records. I find myself manually doing this operation many times, so  I was hoping for a nice standard solution.

Comment: @Evert - Gotcha. Indeed Quassoni's answer best suits your need. I am not familiar with any standard or more elegant solution.